# How to replace NULL values with 0 using Razor Script?

Tags: c#

I have an array of values that contain NULL values. I am using razor script to iterate through these values. I am having an issue with replacing my NULL values with 0. Here is my code:

```
    var dataArray = new Array();
    @foreach (var record in Model)
        {

            if (record.rate === null){

                record.rate = 0;

            } 

            @:var floatRate = parseFloat("@record.rate");
            @:var longDate = parseInt("@record.date");
            @:dataArray.push([longDate, floatRate]);

        }

    console.log(dataArray);
```

This doesn't seem to be working at all. Also, know that the incoming value that I am iterating over is a string which is why there's a float conversion.

Comment: you also have '===' (three equal signs) insteat of two '=='.

Comment: "This doesn't seem to be working at all" - so what *does* happen? And why are you emitting Javascript to parse the value rather than just emitting the value itself into the Javascript? (Or better, just emitting JSON...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have '===' instead of '=='. You should only have two equal signs when checking for null, not three.

Use String.IsNullOrEmpty instead of '==' signs checking for nulls.  Your string might be empty, and not null, thus it is not assigning the value.

```
var dataArray = new Array();
@foreach (var record in Model)
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(record.rate)){

            record.rate = 0;

        } 

        @:var floatRate = parseFloat("@record.rate");
        @:var longDate = parseInt("@record.date");
        @:dataArray.push([longDate, floatRate]);

    }

console.log(dataArray);
```

Comment: I get the following error: Cannot implictly convert int to string

Comment: "Also, know that the incoming value that I am iterating over is a string which is why there's a float conversion." as I quoted you above mentioning that the value you are iterating over is a string, this error means you are not.  Just use '==' instead of '===', and leave out the String.IsNullOrEmpty for now

Comment: try this `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(record.rate.tostring()))`

Comment: I just added if (record.rate == null ) {record.rate = "0";} and it worked.